# Iron hunter mistake!

Tags: infinity-blade-2

Ok so I accidentally killed the iron hunter so I finished that rebirth and wanted to go try him again to get the heavy weapon and now he won't appear?! Can I ever get that weapon again?

Comment: What is the Iron hunter and how do you get to him?

Answer (score 1):

When the Iron Hunter's health bar depletes by two thirds, he will yield, and the player can decide whether to finish or spare him. If spared, the Iron Hunter will return in the next Rebirth and gift Siris with Torren's Legacy, a weapon forged by his ancestor. If killed, the Iron Hunter will drop the Hunter Mail.