# Who is the Iron Hunter and Where is he located?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

I saw this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123804/iron-hunter-mistake) and wondered to my self, "Who is the Iron Hunter, where is he located, and why was he imprisoned?"

Comment: Why was it down voted?

Comment: probably because this is very easy to google: http://infinityblade.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Hunter

Comment: Dominic: That doesn't matter.  The point of this site is to **become** the top google-result for all gaming questions.  I don't think this is a particularly great question, but I've +1-ed because this doesn't deserve a score of -4.

Comment: Also the wiki does not give any back story on this guy? I was also wondering about that.

Comment: @BlueRaja Sure it matters. "Shows no research, is not useful" is exactly what downvotes are for.

Answer (score 1):

The Iron Hunter is in one of the sky cages. The room where these cages are unlocked requires a large key. The door to the room is on the staircase leading up to the final battle with Thane.

Comment: That edit has not happened? You haven't answered "who".

Comment: I edited the question not the answer. I only have an answer to where, and not who.